# Match URI by the asterisk

Tags: php, regex, arrays, uri

What I want to do is to automatically match the URI, and assign the correct description to them. Lets say I have the following URI's:

```
test
something/action
controller/test
controller/another
controller/action/something
action
action/test
controller/another/somethingelse
```

They are really random, but now I would like to use the following array (array, because I think it would be the best solution), to match them:

```
$config = array(
     'test' => 'The description of test',
     'something/action' => 'Some action description',
     'controller/another' => 'Another description',
     'controller/action/*' => 'This should match the `controller/action/blah` and everything similar like: `controller/action/something` and give this description'
     'action' => 'Action description',
     'action/*' => 'As the 2nd above, this should match the `action/test` itself, and similar like `action/anothertest` URI
);
```

This would be easy, in case of no asterisks... (simply `$config[$uri]` to match the description) but I would like to match the asterisks as well... So if there is a controller like `controller/another/name` and I would use the config like `controller/another/*` it would match the description for this array key.

Anyone have an idea on how could it be done? I need ideas basically, but any other answers are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by combining [`fnmatch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) and something like [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$str=file_get_contents(/*... URIs ...*/);
$config = array(
     'test' => 'The description of test',
     'something/action' => 'Some action description',
     'controller/another' => 'Another description',
     'controller/action/*' => 'This should match the `controller/action/blah` and everything similar like: `controller/action/something` and give this description',
     'action' => 'Action description',
     'action/*' => 'As the 2nd above, this should match the `action/test` itself, and similar like `action/anothertest` URI'
);
foreach(explode("\n",$str) as $line)
{
    $line=trim($line);
    $dkey=array_filter(array_keys($config),function($key)use($line){return fnmatch($key,$line);});
    if(count($dkey)<=0)
    {
        echo "(no description)";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $config[reset($dkey)];
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/KheIO)

The above code outputs:

```
The description of test
Some action description
(no description)
Another description
This should match the `controller/action/blah` and everything similar like: `controller/action/something` and give this description
Action description
As the 2nd above, this should match the `action/test` itself, and similar like `action/anothertest` URI
(no description)
```

The above code can be improved: you can cache the `array_keys` result outside loop so it don't need to be called over and over again.

Comment: Thats clever! Didnt knew about the `fnmatch` function, which is awesome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

what you want is `.*`. `.` is in regex [the character class, that matches any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (by default except newlines) and then you need the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` to say match any character 0 or more times.

So your regex would look like

```
controller/action/.*
```

to match

> controller/action/
>   controller/action/blah
>   controller/action/something
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

Suggested solution:

This will return all the descriptions that is comparable to the uri. There is room for improvement here. Cheers!

```
<?php

    $uris = array(
        'test',
        'something/action',
        'controller/test',
        'controller/another',
        'controller/action/something',
        'action',
        'action/test',
        'controller/another/somethingelse'
    );

    $sUri = $uris[4];
    print_r(
        getConfigBasedOnKey($sUri)
    );

    function getConfigBasedOnKey($sUri) {

        $config = array(
             'test' => 'The description of test',
             'something/action' => 'Some action description',
             'controller/another' => 'Another description',
             'controller/action/*' => 'This should match the controller/action/blah and everything similar like: controller/action/something and give this description',
             'action' => 'Action description',
             'action/*' => 'As the 2nd above, this should match the `action/test` itself, and similar like action/anothertest URI'
        );

        $descriptions = array();
        foreach($config as $configKey => $configDescription) {
            $configKey = preg_replace("/\*/",".*",$configKey);

            preg_match("|^$configKey$|",$sUri,$matches);
            if(count($matches) > 0) {
                $descriptions[] = $configDescription;
            }
        }

        return $descriptions;
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This should match the controller/action/blah and everything similar like: controller/action/something and give this description
)
```